# How does the "r" suffix correspond to a floating point number when using MASM?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, masm, masm32

When using MASM I find no information on how a value is formatted in floating point hex.
For example: What is a decimal value of 50.1 equal to when using the "r" suffix?

Also according to the MASM documentation that I have:

a floating point value cannot be a immediate value. If that is true than the following instructions below should be in error in MASM but MASM assembles them with no error:

```
    mov eax,1r ;What is "1r" = in decimal
    mov eax,42ae0000r
```

MASM assembles them as follows:

```
    B8 0000005C     mov eax,1r
    B8 19B6A492     mov eax,42ae0000r
```

Also from testing:

When the instruction below is assembled:

```
    mov eax,1.2r
```

MASM gives this error:

```
    error A2050: real or BCD number not allowed
```

A value with the "r" suffix can NOT have a "." in it. If the "r" suffix is being used.
Is this correct?

From this example if a value is allowed to be a immediate value and has a "r" suffix, with no comma in it, then it is not a hex floating point value. So what is it?

Comment: Could we please stop saying 'decimal' when we mean 'floating point'?

Comment: FWIW, `jwasm` does do what [Cody's currently deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59778981/547981) says - it uses the provided hex value directly. So `mov eax, 1r` is `b8 01 00 00 00`. As such it's little different from writing `mov eax, 0x1`. Not sure what `masm` is doing, if it really is doing what you claim it is.

Comment: So should an assembler allow a floating point as a immediate value in a instruction?